# Finding Area of a shape

Tags: geometry

I'm doing some revision and I'm a bit stuck. How do you find out the area of this shape?

I know you have to do 10cm x 2cm = 20cm devided by 2 = 10cm - 2cm x ? (something) = area.

I'm not sure what the cm of the line next to 10cm is (the question mark bit). I mean would you do 13cm - 10cm = 3cm to find the missing length. Or would it be 2cm like the other side?

Would it be 6cm squared or 4cm squared.

Btw that corner bit is not part of the shape, it's only the 2 sides traingle without the right angle... that's just added on so I can work it out.

P.S. I know this is an easy question but it's bugging me.

[image: Finding the Area of Shape]

Answer (score 1):

Your triangle is not one, as $2 + 10 \lt 13$.  But let's change the $2$ to $4$ so it makes a triangle.  If you know the three sides, you can find the area of a triangle from [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).  Define $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$, then the area $A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$

To do what you are drawing, let the extension of the 10 side to the right angle be $x$, the side from the right angle to the corner near "2 cm" be $y$.  We have $x^2+y^2=4^2=16$ (because I made that side $4$ long).  We also have $y^2+(10+x)^2=y^2+x^2+20x+100=13^2=169$.  This gives $116+20x=169$ or $x=\frac {53}{20}, y=\sqrt {16-(\frac {53}{20})^2}$ and finally the area of your original triangle is half the base times the height, $\frac 12 (10)y$

Answer (score 0):

Use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to find the area of a triangle given its sides.